# CUDA libcublas.so.11 Error when using GPUs inside ONNX Docker Container

Tags: python, onnx, onnxruntime

While programming with python3.6 on DGX Station (NVIDIA) based on ONNX runtime environment;

Using following libraries;

mxnet==1.5.x
onnxruntime-gpu==1.7.x

I see following error

```
OSError: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by updating CUDA to 11.0

```
apt update
apt install cuda-11.0
pip3 uninstall mxnet-cu92 //and reinstall mxnet-cu102
pip3 uninstall onnxruntime-gpu //and resinstall latest version
```

then a new error started appearing

```
onnxruntime cuda failure 100 no cuda-capable device is detected
```

then it was noted that docker was not started with nvidia runtime so following was added to the docker-compose file

```
runtime: nvidia
```

and all started working